# do.call("["...) function in R

Tags: r, function, do.call

I'm learning R so I am sorry if my question sounds too basic. Here's a function I wrote to create subtable from table. I am following Norman Matloff's book. So, I'm again sorry if you believe that there is shorter method to do this. I'm learning right now, so longer methods will only help me to affirm my understanding about R

```
subtable <- function(tbl,subnames)
{
  tblarray <- unclass(tbl)
  dcargs <-list(tblarray)
  ndims <- length(subnames) # number of dimensions
  for(i in 1:ndims)
  {
    dcargs[[i+1]]<-subnames[[i]]
  }
  subarray <-do.call("[",dcargs) ###LINE1###
  dims <-lapply (subnames,length)
  subtbl<-array(subarray,dims,dimnames = subnames)
  class(subtbl)<-"table"
  return(subtbl)
}
```

Now when I call the function using:

```
ct<-read.table("ct.dat",header=T)
```

where ct.dat is:

```
"Vote.for.X" "Voted.for.X.Last.Time"
"Yes" "Yes"
"Yes" "No"
"No" "No"
"Not Sure" "Yes"
"No" "No"
```

Now, I'd call

```
cttable<-table(ct)
subtable(cttable,subnames<-list(Vote.for.X=c("No","Yes"), Voted.for.X.Last.Time=c("No","Yes"))
```

I got the correct subtable. However, I have no clue what LINE1 is doing.

I executed the code line-by-line to see what's going on. Here's what I got after calling the for loop:

```
> dcargs
[[1]]
          Voted.for.X.Last.Time
Vote.for.X No Yes
  No        2   0
  Not Sure  0   1
  Yes       1   1

[[2]]
[1] "No"  "Yes"

[[3]]
[1] "No"  "Yes"
```

Now, I understand that dcargs will be function argument for "[". Other than that I have no clue what's going with LINE 1. I'm really stuck.

Any help please?

Comment: `do.call(\`[\`, dcargs)` translates to `tbl[c("No","Yes"), c("No", Yes")]`

Comment: Maybe this will be enlightening - all of the following are identical - `do.call(\`[\`, list(cttable, c("No","Yes"), c("No","Yes")) )` and `\`[\`(cttable, c("No","Yes"), c("No","Yes"))` and `cttable[c("No","Yes"), c("No","Yes")]`

Comment: thanks thelatemail. I have two follow-up questions: 1) why did you use "tbl" table? I don't see "tbl" in Line 1 at all. 2) For future reference, how can I know which table is being called? I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: `tbl` is the original function argument - it gets assigned to `tblarray`, which then gets put into `dcargs`. So, it's essentially still `tbl`. The table/object being subset is always the first argument to the `\`[\`` function

Comment: Thanks thelatemail. So, I read the help document. It seems that the function `[` first references dcargs[[1]] which is nothing but a copy of tbl. Then dcargs[[2] and dcargs[[3]] extract the respective row and column using subsetting. Am I correct? I'd sincerely appreciate your thoughts. I did struggle with this example for about 5 hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with @thelatemail great comment, you can also get more information from the help page `help('[')` which reads

> indexing by [ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the specified element(s)

and from the help to function `do.call` we read

> do.call constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.

This line is calling the `[` function with the list argument dcargs (named because they are do.call arguments). Since the elements of dcargs are indices of the table, what this line is doing is referencing the relevant indices of the list object, contained in [[2]] and [[3]], which it is going to index.

In short, `do.call("[",dcargs)` indexes the no and yes rows and the no and yes columns of `dcargs[[1]]`.